# Google Maps API v3 returning incorrect lat/lng for South African address

Tags: google-maps

I am plotting a map using south african addresses. This in general works fine but in some instances the API seems unable to find the address and returns the same lat/lng plotted in the centre of the country. I am using the following function to retrieve the coordinates:

```
function getpointfromaddress(location, callbackfunction){
var geocoderRequest = { address: location, componentRestrictions: {country: 'ZA'} };
geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
var point =  results[0].geometry.location
callbackfunction(point)
}
})
}
```

An example of an address that won't map is "Corner of Witkoppen & Nanyuki Rd,Sunninghill Park,Sandton,2199". The address maps fine using google maps online.

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: You can try to use the [Google Geocoding API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), a sample request for your input will be like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Corner%20of%20Witkoppen%20&%20Nanyuki%20Rd,Sunninghill%20Park,Sandton,2199&key=YOUR_API_KEY it should show some lat/lon in South Africa in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be because of the '&' in your address. Calling the address directly from google maps generates the following link.

```
https://www.google.co.in/maps/search/Corner+of+Witkoppen+%26+Nanyuki+Rd,Sunninghill+Park,Sandton,2199/@-26.029296,28.0215236,14z/data=!3m1!4b1
```

The '&' is replaced with '%26' in the query. 
You can accomplish this in your program by URL encoding the address or by replacing it programmatically in Javascript.